# How to properly destructure assignment with dynamic key? (react/destructuring-assignment)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm just getting an eslint error about destructuring this code, but I have no idea how it should look. In this instance, I will probably just ignore this warning as this code is already pretty succinct, but, I am curious how it would be destructured. Any ideas or guidance is appreciated.

```
  _onChange = (e, key) => {
    const edited = { ...this.state[key] }; <--- this line is throwing the eslint error
    edited[e.name] = e.value;
    this.setState({
      [key]: edited,
    });
  };
```

Comment: It is saying that `this.state[key]` is not defined? or can't be sure that it is an object?

Comment: [`const { [key]: obj } = this.state;`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1744)

Comment: @James [`react/destructuring-assignment`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/5fac02c27d9b9d10a786c788f7b322009de04426/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destructure into dynamically named variables in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939289/how-to-destructure-into-dynamically-named-variables-in-es6)

Comment: Oups, maybe wrong dupe target, this one is maybe more relevant: [How to destructure an object based on a dynamic defined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54064859/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Hey, I posted an answer, could you take a look and see if it's incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

so, I was able to get there with the comments.

At the end of the day, I realized I just needed 'edited' to be an object containing the destructured object.

```
 _onChange = (e, key) => {
    const { [key]: { ...edited } } = this.state;
    edited[e.name] = e.value;
    this.setState({
      [key]: edited,
    });
  };
```

Here, `edited` will become { ...this.state[key] } which, after comparison, looks to be the same result as the previous code, but using the destructuring assignment.

I hope people will comment if they feel this is incorrect.

Even more simple, suggestion by [Emile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron)!

```
 _onChange = (e, key) => {
    const { [key]: current } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      [key]: { ...current, [e.name]: e.value },
    });
  };
```

Comment: It could even be simplified a little: `const { [key]: current } = this.state; this.setState({ [key]: { ...current, [e.name]: e.value }})`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's awesome, I'ma add that