# How to filter object members

Tags: javascript

Assume we have

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
```

and we want to remove some members. For example `c` and `d`:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 };
```

Is there a cleaner immutable way than

```
const keysToRemove = ['c', 'd'];
Object.keys(obj)
   .filter(key => !keysToRemove.includes(key))
   .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
      return acc;
   } , {});
```

Comment: While that link is similar, this question here does not require a method which uses destructuring. Using destructuring here would look pretty messy IMO

Comment: a clear duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54064859/1447675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original object's entries, you can filter it to construct a new array of entries, without the keys in `keysToRemove`. Then create a new object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const keysToRemove = ['c', 'd'];
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => !keysToRemove.includes(key))
);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: This has one iteration less than my code. It's an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fewer keys to remove then you can destructuring assignment with a spread operator. Or you can use the delete operator.

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const {c, d, ...filteredObj} = obj;
console.log(filteredObj); // {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
const {
  c,
  d,
  ...filteredObj
} = obj;
console.log(filteredObj);
```

Comment: This is pretty neat if the keys to remove are static. but I determine the dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In these circumstances, I would always prefer the classic `for...in` loop. It's simpler, cleaner and more readable.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const keysToRemove = ['c', 'd'];
let newObj = {};
for (let key in obj) {
    if(!keysToRemove.includes(key)) {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
console.log(newObj);    //outputs {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const ignoreKeys = ['c', 'd'];
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => !ignoreKeys.includes(key))
);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL Good point. This answer has one iteration less than mine, so it's an improvement already. but it's still pretty verbose. The `Array` interface has `filter`, `reduce`, `splice` and many other methods which come handy with these problems, but `Object` doesn't seem to offer such methods. You have to convert to array, perform actions and create an object from the new array.

Comment: The code filters the actual object entries  to build a new array of entries, excluding the keys in ignoreKeys.

Answer (score 0):

computed property names can be used  having dummy target property. you can learn more about this here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

```
var originalObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
    keysToRemove = ['c', 'd'];
    result = keysToRemove.reduce((total, key) => {
        const { [key]: dummy, ...remainder } = total;
        return remainder;
    }, originalObj);
console.log(result);
```